# Modifying unnamed objects via r-value semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have a method that modifies objects passed by reference:

```
class MyClass;

MyClass& modify (MyClass& x) { ...; return x; }
```

What's the right way to extend `modify` to unnamed objects avoiding extra copies, so that the following code is valid?

```
MyClass createMyClass () { ... }

MyClass x = modify(createMyClass());

// instead of:

MyClass x = createMyClass();
modify(x);
```

PS: `MyClass` implements efficient moving.

Comment: Perfect forwarding for the argument, and return by value for RVO?

Comment: `T t = modify(create_T());` will always create a minimum of two objects. Unless moving is efficient enough, stick to creating and modifying in two steps.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, `T` implements move constructor/assignment.

Comment: `T& modify (T&& t) { return modify(t); }`?

Comment: `class T;` is an unfortunate naming, as usually used in template.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wouldn't `modify(create_T())` then return a dangling reference?

Comment: @DanielLangr: `T t = modify(create_T());` would be ok, temporary end at `;` and has been modified and copied before. `auto&& t = modify(create_T());` would be problematic though as `t` would be a dangling reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this code works with perfect forwarding, but not sure if you like it or not:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct T {
    T() {std::cout << this << " ctor\n";}
    ~T() {std::cout << this << " dtor\n";}
    T(const T& t) {std::cout << this << " cc\n"; i = t.i;}
    T(T&& t) {std::cout << this << " mc\n"; i = t.i;}
    T& operator=(const T& t) {std::cout << this << " ca\n"; i = t.i; return *this;}
    T& operator=(T&& t) {std::cout << this << " ma\n"; i = t.i; return *this;}
    int i = 0;
};

//T& modify (T& t) {t.i++; return t; }
template<typename X>
X modify (X&& t) { t.i++; return t; }

T create_T () { return T{}; }

int main() {

    T t1 = modify(create_T());
    std::cout << t1.i << "\n----------\n";

    // instead of:

    T t2 = create_T();
    modify(t2);
    std::cout << t2.i << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And output will be like this:

```
0x7fff616d0fe0 ctor
0x7fff616d0fe8 mc
0x7fff616d0fe0 dtor
1
----------
0x7fff616d0fd8 ctor
1
0x7fff616d0fd8 dtor 
0x7fff616d0fe8 dtor
```

You can also replace prefect forwarding with these 2 lines:

```
T& modify (T& t) { t.i++; return t; }
T modify (T&& t) { t.i++; return t; }
```

but not very interesting method.

**Update:**
For the reason that I don't know, following code does not generate similar output like perfect forwarding:

```
auto modify (auto&& t) { t.i++; return t; }
```

and output will be like this:

```
0x7ffcfa65c9a8 ctor
0x7ffcfa65c9b0 mc
0x7ffcfa65c9a8 dtor
1
----------
0x7ffcfa65c9a8 ctor
0x7ffcfa65c9b8 cc
0x7ffcfa65c9b8 dtor
1
0x7ffcfa65c9a8 dtor
0x7ffcfa65c9b0 dtor
```

Maybe the more experienced ones can tell the reasoning behind this difference.

Comment: @Jarod42 Updated. sorry, missed that one.